# Rudin Theorem: quotient of functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-explanation

The setting for Theorem 4.4(c) in Baby Rudin is:

> Suppose $E \subset X$, a metric space, $p$ is a limit point of $E$, $f$ and $g$ are complex functions on $E$, and $\lim\limits_{x \to p} f(x) = A$, $\lim\limits_{x \to p} g(X) = B$, then $\lim\limits_{x \to p} \left(\frac{f}{g}\right)(x) = \frac{A}{B}$, if $B \neq 0$.

Part (a) and (b) were addition and multiplication, but I think I understand those. I can't fully and rigorously justify (b). I need to use Theorem 4.2 which relates limits of sequences to limits of functions and the analogous properties for sequences. So I should be able to reduce this a product of sequences with $s_n =f(x_n)$ and $t_n = \frac{1}{g(x_n)}$, but I need this to be true for *all* $x_n \neq p$ such that $x_n \to p$, which I cannot do If $g(x_n) = 0$ anywhere.

Does anyone have tips for how to rigorously justify this?

Comment: choose $N$ large enough such that for all $m > N, g(x_m) \neq 0$.

Comment: There is no sequence in this question. @ureui

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Definition 4.3, the quotient function $f/g$ is only defined on the subset $F := \{x \in E: g(x) \neq 0\}$. This means Theorem 4.2 needs to be applied to the tuple $(X, Y, F, f/g, p)$. In other words, the test sequences $\{p_n\}$ need to lie in $F$, the domain of $f/g$, so that $\lim_{n \to \infty} (f/g)(p_n)$ makes sense.

Comment: It makes sense to me (and I missed it, I think) that the domain of the function has to be $x$ such that $g(x) \neq 0$. How do we, from the definition, say that $g(p_n) \neq 0 $ as well? Is it as simple as "we need $\lim (f/g)p_n$ to actually be defined"? So, in other words, I can safely assume we are only taking $p_n$ so that $g(p_n) \neq 0$?

Comment: Yes, you're choosing the sequences $\{p_n\}$ from $F$ where $f/g$ is defined, so that $g(p_n) \neq 0$ (this was the definition of the domain of $f/g$).